# Hash sha-256 Java

Tags: java

Как рациональнее преобразовать данные(строку) в хэш sha-256?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531455/how-to-hash-some-string-with-sha256-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно получить соответствующий digest объект и использовать его:

```java
import java.security.MessageDigest;

String text = "...";
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(text.getBytes());
```

Учтите, что статический метод `MessageDigest.getInstance` может бросать исключение `NoSuchAlgorithmException` (т.к список доступных алгоритмом может отличаться на разных машинах (хотя SHA256 должен быть у всех), [этот список можно посмотреть так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24983009/5308802)), что нужно указать в Вашем методе:

```java
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public static byte[] getSha256(String text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    return MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(text.getBytes());
}
```